Attempting to JIT compile method error in .net maui net 8 version
I am creating .net MAUI Application with .net 8 version. i want to get all connected device with mac system for implement this functionality i use following code for Mac Platform.
ProcessStartInfo processInfo = new ProcessStartInfo
            {
                FileName = "/usr/sbin/system_profiler",
                Arguments = "SPUSBDataType",
                RedirectStandardOutput = true,
                UseShellExecute = false,
                CreateNoWindow = true
            };

            using (Process process = Process.Start(processInfo))
            {
                if (process != null)
                {
                    string output = process.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd();
                    result = ParseUSBDeviceOutput(output);
                    process.WaitForExit();
                }
            }

then i got following error :
> System.ExecutionEngineException: Attempting to JIT compile method
> 'void
> System.Runtime.Serialization.SerializationGuard:<ThrowIfDeserializationInProgress>g__ThrowIfDeserializationInProgress|0_0
> (System.Runtime.Serialization.SerializationInfo,string,int&)' while
> running in aot-only mode. See
> https://docs.microsoft.com/xamarin/ios/internals/limitations for more
> information.

this error also occur when i use any method of Emgu.CV library.
Note : this problem occur in only mac platform. in window working well.

Have you checked the link in the error? Especially no dynamic code generation and runtime disabled features sections.

I think this is relevant https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/mac/internals/aot
